# WPF DataGrid Some checkboxes being reset on scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I've got a C# WPF application with a datagrid.  I have a custom class with a handful of public boolean properties, each with a get and set.

```
 public class OutlookPST
{
    public FileInfo PSTFileInfo { get; set; }   

    public Boolean Attached { get; set; }
    public Boolean FileLocal { get; set; }
    public Boolean LatestVersion { get; set; }
    public Boolean BackupExists { get; set; }
    public Boolean IgnoreDuplicate { get; set; }

    public Boolean CopyToLocalFlag { get; set; }
    public Boolean BackupToNetworkFlag { get; set; }
```

In the xaml file, I have itemsource="Binding".

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPSTs" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="243" Width="1193"/>
```

I'm setting the datagrid ItemsSource property to a list of this custom class.

```
private void OutlookPSTToDatagrid(List<OutlookPST> PSTs)
    {
        try
        {   
            dgPSTs.ItemsSource = PSTs;
```

When I do this, all the initial data looks good.  All the boolean flags are checkboxes, which is what I want.  All the data is correct.  When I scroll down, just two of the boolean flags get set to checked.  And when I scroll back up, the first rows are also checked, when they weren't before.

I don't understand how it's working for some of the flags and not the others.

Anyone have any ideas?  I can post some code if required.  Just let me know what parts of the code.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried debugging to see what is setting the boolean flags to the incorrect value?

Comment: how is anyone supposed to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: Hi Functor! Can you edit the question and add your code? We'll be able to give you a better answer once we can see your implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was a pair of improperly formed lambda expressions elsewhere in the code:

```
if (outlookPSTs.Where(x => x.CopyToLocalFlag = true).Count() > 0)
```

instead of:

```
if (outlookPSTs.Where(x => x.CopyToLocalFlag == true).Count() > 0)
```

Same sort of thing for the other boolean flag.